# Laravel: How to create a folder in public path dynamically when a file is uploaded?

Tags: php, laravel, file, eloquent, directory

I have created a function which stores file path in database and stores the file in public/uploads/release folder. Here is my Controller:

```
$reference = $request->get('reference');
    $uploads = array();
    if($files = $request->file('uploads'))
    {  
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('uploads/release', $name);
        $uploads[] = $name;
    }
```

Here I am storing file in public/uploads/release folder, but now I want to create a folder dynamically every time a file is uploaded, and the folder must be the value from the $reference variable.
e.g: reference is 'ABC123'. Then the file must be automatically stored in public/uploads/release/ABC123 folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Storage::makeDirectory(public_path('uploads/release/'.$reference));`

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#directories

Or you can also do

`$file->move(public_path('uploads/release/'.$reference), $name);`

Answer (score 5):

You can use File Class in laravel

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

$path = public_path().'/uploads/release/'.$request->get('reference');
if (! File::exists($path)) {
    File::makeDirectory($path);
}
```

Comment: is it store in storage folter?